# How to put records from a random access file into an array in the C programming language?

Tags: c, file

How do I put the records from the random access file DATA.data into the array allRecs[10]?

```
/*Reading a random access file and put records into an array*/
#include <stdio.h>

/*  somestruct structure definition */
struct somestruct{
    char namn[20];
    int artNr;
}; /*end structure somestructure*/

int main (void) {
    int i = 0;
    FILE *file; /* DATA.dat file pointer */
    /* create data with default information */
    struct somestruct rec = {"", 0};
    struct somestruct allRecs[10]; /*here we can store all the records from the file*/
    /* opens the file; exits it file cannot be opened */
    if((file = fopen( "DATA.dat", "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("File couldn't be opened\n");
    } 
    else { 
        printf("%-16s%-6s\n", "Name", "Number");
        /* read all records from file (until eof) */
        while ( !feof( file) ) { 
            fread(&rec, sizeof(struct somestruct), 1, file);
            /* display record */
            printf("%-16s%-6d\n", rec.namn, rec.artNr);
            allRecs[i].namn = /* HOW TO PUT NAME FOR THIS RECORD IN THE STRUCTARRAY allRecs? */
            allRecs[i].artNr = /* HOW TO PUT NUMBER FOR THIS RECORD IN THE STRUCTARRAY allRecs? */
            i++;
        }/* end while*/
        fclose(file); /* close the file*/
    }/* end else */
    return 0; 
}/* end main */
```

Comment: Homework? If so, please tag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways immediately come to mind. First, you can simply assign, like this:

```
allRecs[i] = rec;
```

But, judging by your code, you don't even need that - you can simply read directly in the appropriate element:

```
fread(&allRecs[i], sizeof(struct somestruct), 1, file);
/* display record */
printf("%-16s%-6d\n", allRecs[i].namn, allRecs[i].artNr);
i++;
```

By the way - are you sure that the file will never contain more than 10 records? Because if it does, you'll get into a lot of trouble this way...

Comment: No I'm not sure the how do you make it dynamic?